# Deployed express server isn't creating a session?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session, session-cookies

I have deployed a node express server on digital ocean. However, it won't create the session once it's deployed. I added a store to prevent memory leak and initialized
`app.set('trust proxy', 1)`, before the session. I am creating a user for the session once the user is authenticated. The snippet below shows the configuration for the session.

```
app.use(
    session({
        key: "userid",
        secret: "subscribe",
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        store: sessionStore,
        cookie: {
            expires: 60000 * 60,
            domain: ".section-webapp-y793v.ondigitalocean.app"
        }
    })
)

app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
    if (req.session.user) {
        res.send({ loggedIn: true, user: req.session.user })
    } else {
        res.send({ loggedIn: false })
    }
}
)
```

Comment: what is "sessionStore"?

Comment: database to save the session

Comment: and where is it initialized? can you share the code?

Comment: Store works fine that is not the issue

Comment: As you say then) all looks okay from what you show)

Comment: Yeah, it works fine on localhost but not production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the issue was with the server. Since I had applied secure:true, it wouldn't work since the production server wasn't secured with SSL. Then I also changed the cookies to sameSite:none.

````
app.use(
    session({
        key: "userid",
        secret: "subscribe",
        resave: false,
        store: sessionStore,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        cookie: {
            expires: 60000 * 60,
            secure: true, 
            sameSite: "none"
        }
    })
)```
````